Low level orbit
What’s the lowest altitude for an orbit? Is there any limitation? I have looked in the internet for a reference but couldn’t find any.

This should be asked on Space.SE, rather than Aviation, although they might close it as a duplicate of one of these: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/66616/17995 https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41887/17995 https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50147/17995 https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48880/17995

This is more a question for space.se. However it has some aviation aspects too.
There is no limit per se for a satellite orbit. Air molecules are detectable very far from Earth surface, though their density continuously drops with altitude. The ISS orbits at about 400 km, but air is still present until the thermopause, that is an altitude of 500 to 1000 km.
Still, the practical low limit for orbiting seems to be 160 km.
Low Earth Orbit satellites
So most satellites have to oppose air drag of various intensity. Drag slows them down and decreases their orbital height. A satellite must be reboosted from time to time with an engine to re-accelerate the vehicle and rise it to a higher orbit. The required force is provided either by thrusters (jets) or ion engines. The reboost capacity is limited in time by the satellite design.
The lower the orbit, the more important the drag, the more frequent the reboosts. For a low orbit, either the quantity of fuel must be increased, which makes the launch more expensive, or the lifetime is reduced.
The Japanese satellite SLATS maintained a height as low as 167 km during 7 days using both thrusters and ion engines.
See also:

Very low Earth orbit (VLEO
How low can satellites go?

Note orbits are not necessarily circular, they can be eccentric, with a maximum and a minimum altitude. For an eccentric orbit, the satellite velocity varies along the path.
Kármán line
The practical limit for orbiting seems to be 160 km.
There is a reason, descending below requires a huge quantity of fuel for reboost, and the lifetime is very short. Still a low orbit can be useful for a short mission, e.g. with space-based radars, which power can be divided by 4 when the height is divided by 2.
In the other direction, the velocity of an aircraft must be increased as it flies higher, the reason is lift depends on the number of air molecules in contact with the wing per unit of time. Less air creates less lift unless the wing area is increased, but this has a limit, or velocity is increased.
Near altitudes of 90-115 km, an aircraft must fly at some velocity, and a satellite must orbit at about the same velocity to maintain a circular orbit and not fall. This is where flight in air and orbiting in space meet.
For this reason, the height of 100 km, named the Kármán line, is the "official" limit between atmosphere and space. More accurately, the height where flying with lift and orbiting require exactly the same velocity is 110 km, known as the maximum equilibrium velocity.
You can read more about this aspect in: Does Karman line depend on the wing area, and if not, why?
Is it easier to fly below 110 km than to orbit:

You can fly at velocities below the ones required for orbiting.

Materials used for the satellite must resist heating from drag, there is a practical limit.

Aerodynamics becomes a factor, the satellite design must be changed, this may not be compatible with the satellite functional requirements (e.g. antennas and solar arrays).

More fuel is required to reboost the satellite for a sustained orbit. There is also a practical limit.


